# Prevent creation of empty embedded docs

Tags: mongoose

The json data I POST is in the form:

```
{
"name": "john",
"tags": [{
    "chapter": "",
    "comment": ""
}]
}
```

There is a way to avoid the creation of an empty embedded document (with its own ObjectId) with empty fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple method could be done through custom `set` method in the data schema

```
function removeEmpty(v) {
    if (!v || 0 === v.length)
    {
        return undefined;  // remove this field if its value is empty string
    }
    return v;
}

var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    tags: [{
        _id: false,    // remove `_id` for subdocument.
        chapter: {type: String, set: removeEmpty},
        comment: {type: String, set: removeEmpty}
    }]
});
```

With save data codes as below

```
var d = new Data({
    "name": "john"
});
d.tags.push({"chapter": "", "comment": ""})

d.save(function(err) {
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e676b9fd12dad01cd5ed7f"), "name" : "john", "tags" : [ {  }
 ], "__v" : 0 }
```

If we want to remove this empty `tags` array totally, per [this question](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1335), with `.pre('save'`

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({});
}

DataSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var isEmpty = true;
    if (this.tags) {
        this.tags.forEach(function(obj) {
            if (!isEmptyObject(obj))
                isEmpty = false;
        })
        if (isEmpty) {
            this.tags = undefined; 
        }           
    }
    next();
})
```

---

Please try to remove the empty embedded document through [`.pre('save'`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) middleware. Remove the subdocument if their fields are empty string.

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

YourSchmea.pre('save', function(next){
    this.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        if (isEmpty(tag.chapter) && isEmpty(tag.comment)) {
            delete tag.chapter;
            delete tag.comment;
        }
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this solution would take a huge work, I have 15 embedded documents type for each for 4 type of documents.
I tought there was schema option for this..